# I can't run selenium using python with visual studio code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am completely new to code and was trying to create an instabot with Python and Selenium.

I have installed selenium through pip.

but can't run it
[image]

so any help is welcome.

Thank you

Thomas

I have tried installing it several times but... didn't work

Comment: what is the output of `pip show selenium` i your vs code terminal?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created a virtual environment for your project. Try installing Selenium using the VS terminal or create a new project without using venv.

Comment: I tried to install it trough the VS terminal and then run the code after but noothing.
Selenium is installed but VS does not seem to find it.
.../Users/thomaseucat/Desktop/Capture d’écran 2023-06-24 à 01.10.07.png

Comment: I have tried this command also (this is the folder's path  I want to install it in) 

/Users/thomaseucat/Code/Bot1 python3 -m install selenium

but got permission denied, I don't know how get the permission....